# Incluir em uma url variavel conunt javascript 'console' chrome

Tags: javascript, string, url, concatenação-de-string

var conta = 1
var conta = 1 + 1

window.open('/teste/numero/11965/', '_blank')

preciso substituir o valor de 11965

pela variavel conta de forma que fique

window.open('/teste/numero/CONTAR/', '_blank')

window.open('/teste/numero/1/', '_blank')
window.open('/teste/numero/2/', '_blank')
window.open('/teste/numero/3/', '_blank')

se tiver como colocar dentro de um loop ou contar 1 to 100000

por gentileza

agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, a string que você quer é uma template string, usando ` no lugar de '

ex: window.open(`/teste/numero/${suaVariavel}/`, '_blank')

o loop ficaria então da seguinte forma:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
  window.open(`/teste/numero/${suaVariavel}/`, '_blank')
  suaVariavel++
}
```

Só substituir suaVariavel pelo nome real

Comment: Esther Maia, obrigado funcionando perfeito grato....